# Automated Sorting in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sorting, macros, sas

I have lots of tables which I would like to sort with Proc Sort. (The names of the tables are written in a text file.) To avoid repeating the same code all over again I have tried creating a macro that would import the text file, create an array consisting of those table names and finally sort all the tables. However, I came across a few problems. In Python, I would easily be able to loop through an array. But in SAS, I am not sure how to do it.

```
%MACRO SORT_TABLES();

PROC IMPORT 
  DATAFILE = 'TABLES_LIST.txt'
  OUT = WORK.TABLES_LIST (RENAME = VAR1 = TABLE_NAME)
  DBMS = TAB
  REPLACE;
  GETNAMES = NO;
QUIT;

/* GET THE LIST OF TABLE NAMES: */
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    INTO :TABLEVAR1 - :TABLEVAR&SYSMAXLONG
  FROM 
    WORK.TABLES_LIST;
  QUIT;

DATA _NULL_;
  ARRAY TABLE_NAMES $ &TABLEVAR1 - &TABLEVAR&SYSMAXLONG;
RUN;

%DO %OVER TABLE_NAMES
  PROC SORT 
    DATA = &TABLEVAR1 /* how can I iterate here???? */ 
    OUT = 'WORK.'||&TABLEVAR1;
    BY A B C;
  QUIT; 
%END;

%MEND;
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to actually import each table in your list? Or have you done that already?

Comment: Are you sorting the dataset in place? Because DATA=FRED and OUT=WORK.FRED will point to the same table unless you are using the USER libref so that one level names don't go into the WORK library.

Comment: Does your input list of tables really have tabs in it?  It looks to me like you are treating like it is just one field per line.

Comment: The import is working fine, the datafile was changed just for the sake of privacy :D however i am not sure how to loop through this array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an iterative `%DO` loop to loop over your "array" of macro variables.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select distinct table_name 
    into :tablevar1 - 
    from table_list
  ;
quit;
%do i=1 %to &sqlobs ;
  proc sort data=&&tablevar&i ; by _all_ ; run;
%end;
```

But you don't need a macro for this. There are easier ways to generate code.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set table_list ;
  put 'PROC SORT DATA = ' table_name '; BY _all_; run;' ;
run;
%include code / source2 ;
```

Comment: But then here comes another issue - the columns are called differently in each table so I'd need to tell SAS something like: SORT BY FIRST 3 columns. Is there a way to do this in SAS? Can't find anything on the Internet.

Comment: Use PROC SQL to sort?  `create table &&tablevar&i as select * from &&tablevar&i order by 1,2,3;`  But you will have trouble if any table has less than 3 columns.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice though to be able to order the tables by the number of columns they have. So if one table has 3 columns ORDER BY 1,2,3 and if another one has 5 columns then ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5. I can't figure out how to tell PROC SQL to order it by all columns. I tried ORDER BY * - didn't work. I also tried to get count of the columns and then create and array but with the following error: ERROR: Librefs are restricted to eight characters. INFORMATION_SCHEMA has been truncated.

Comment: Just use `BY _ALL_;` if you want to sort by all columns.